# window.location.reload() is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am stuck with this problem since yesterday. If I run the below code in chrome and I.E. it works perfectly. It call the "AssignWorkOrders" method in "WorkOrder" and also reload the page at the end to show the changes.

However, when I use Firefox control skips calling to "AssignWorkOrders" method (do not go to AssignWorkOrders) and also do not reload the page.

Also if I comment out the window.location.reload(); control will call "AssignWorkOrders" method for all 3 browsers.

Could you please suggest what is wrong in using window.location.reload??

Any help will be very much appreciated .. I am veryy stuck with firefox. Please Let me know if it is not clear or need any other details ...

```
$.confirm("@Resources.LanguageStrings.ReadyToAssignWorkOrders".format(workOrderIds.length),
                function() {

                var objToSend = { workOrderUpdateParams: workOrderIds };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AssignWorkOrders", "WorkOrder")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    cache: false,
                    data: $.toDictionary(objToSend),
                    success: function(json) {
                        // get a handle to the dataTbale and redraw the page
                        var oTable = $('##WorkOrderList').dataTable();
                        oTable.fnDraw();
                        selectAllComboItems('#SelectedStaff', false);
                        selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);
                    }
                });
                window.location.reload();
            });
```

Comment: because you do it before the Ajax call finishes....

Comment: Where do you suggesting me to call it??

Comment: inside of success?

Comment: I moved reload() to inside the success but it is not reloading my web page in any browser.

Comment: in the success method being called?

Comment: Called in success method. But it is not reloading the page anymore

success: function(json) {
                                // get a handle to the dataTbale and redraw the page
                                var oTable = $('##WorkOrderList').dataTable();
                                oTable.fnDraw();
                                selectAllComboItems('#SelectedStaff', false);
                                selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);
                                window.location.reload();
                            }

Answer (score 1):

You are reloading directly after an asynchronous request. This is going to cause the page to reload before the request has finished. You need to do it inside of the the success method...

```
$.confirm(
    "@Resources.LanguageStrings.ReadyToAssignWorkOrders"
        .format(workOrderIds.length),
                function() {

                var objToSend = { workOrderUpdateParams: workOrderIds };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AssignWorkOrders", "WorkOrder")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    cache: false,
                    data: $.toDictionary(objToSend),
                    success: function(json) {
                        // get a handle to the dataTbale and redraw the page
                        var oTable = $('##WorkOrderList').dataTable();
                        oTable.fnDraw();
                        selectAllComboItems('#SelectedStaff', false);
                        selectAllComboItems('#SelectedVendor', false);
                        // do it here
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });                
            });
```

Comment: Now the control goes to "AssignWorkOrders" function but it didn't reload/refresh the web page.